# Как лучше реализовать фон в блоке?

Tags: css, background

Можно ли такой фон, как в шапке, реализовать на чистом CSS без использования графики?

[image: Фон]

Answer (score 5):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-top: 4px solid #0759B1;
}

.header-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(8, 111, 219, 1);
  border-bottom: 4px solid #0759B1;
}

.header-bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 7px;
  background: rgba(8, 111, 219, 1);
  transform: skew(20deg);
  border-bottom: 4px solid #0759B1;
  border-left: 4px solid #0759B1;
}

.header-bg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -72px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #0759B1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-bg">
    
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, 3d CSS:
https://html5book.ru/3d-transform/
https://habrahabr.ru/post/151300/
А можно и на чистом CSS попробовать. Скруглить левый угол у большого div.